# Client Name vs Client's Each Applications in Resume

Tags: resume

Currently I handle multiple different applications on a client.

Is it better to write down **the client name only** or **list down each applications that handled by me** (currently 3) in my resume?

Comment: Yes correct. This client has some projects for their multiple products on my company which handled by me.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I'd say client name followed by a bullet list of the apps with a very short description (single sentence) of what you did on that app.

Answer (score 0):

If the technology or skill sets you applied to different apps varies, you may want to itemize them. Example:

- Purchase app handled credit card payments
- Analysis app worked with big data.
- Field worker app gathers data using various hardware integration

Otherwise, if they're just: accounts receivable, payable and customer management, just indicate there were 3 to show the scope of the project and there's no need to offer much detail. Focus more on the skills and technology used.